# Error loading Outlook Add-In "Downloading file:///C:Program Files (x86)/.../Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll did not succeed"

Tags: outlook-addin

I have an add-in developed for Outlook 2016 installed on everyone's machine in my company (about 200 users) but on one user's machine the add-in never loads (even under the "Disabled Add-Ins" or "Inactive Add-Ins").  The correct registry key is setup and all of the files are there but I see the following error from the windows event viewer:

> Customization URI: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/.../MyAddIn.vsto
>   Exception: Downloading file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/.../Microsoft.Office.Tools.dll did not succeed

[image: Error message]

I don't understand why it's looking for that file in that particular folder.  I don't see this file on anyone else's machine in that directory and yet my add-in works for them.  I thought that it should be loaded from the GAC (his GAC matches everyone else's with the same "Microsoft.Office.Tools.v9.0").  What could be the problem on his machine?

Note - I'm installing my add-in through a windows installer made using WiX.  I've tried it with both Outlook 32-bit and Outlook 64-bit on his machine and that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The exception detailes belongs to the ClickOnce installer, not MSI (WIX). I'd recommend removing any previous editions of your add-in first.